# Calling hook in onSubmit of a form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, neo4j, react-hooks, react-hook-form

I've recently made a small form in Reactjs so I can get my login credentials from my neo4j database. I'm using the `use-neo4j` hook. The only problem is that I can't trigger my `useReadCypher` to see if I handled the use of the hook correctly. The reason for this is that I want to call my `useReadCypher` inside the `onSubmit` of my form, but the rules of hooks won't allow it. As you can see in the code below

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { useReadCypher } from "use-neo4j";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

function Login() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (form) => {
    const query = "MATCH (u:User) {username: $username, password:$password}) RETURN u";
    const params = { username: form.username, password: form.password };
    const { loading, first } = useReadCypher(query, params);
  };

  return (
    <form
      className="loginForm bg-white shadow-md rounded-md px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 mx-8"
      onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <p className="font-bold text-xl">Login</p>
      <hr className="my-3" />
      <div className="mb-4">
        <label className="text-left block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="username">
          Gebruikersnaam
        </label>
        <input
          className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          id="username"
          type="text"
          placeholder="Gebruikersnaam"
          {...register("username")}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="mb-6">
        <label className="text-left block text-gray-700 text-sm font-bold mb-2" htmlFor="password">
          Wachtwoord
        </label>
        <input
          className="shadow appearance-none border rounded w-full py-2 px-3 text-gray-700 leading-tight focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          id="password"
          name="password"
          type="password"
          placeholder="Wachtwoord"
          {...register("password")}
        />
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-center">
        <input
          className="bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded focus:outline-none focus:shadow-outline"
          type="submit"
          value="Aanmelden"
        />
      </div>
    </form>
  );
}
export default Login;
```

I know it won't work if I keep the `const {loading, first} = useReadCypher(query,params);` in the `onSubmit` part. I also tried using the `useState` to put it in a variable like this:

```
let [result, setResult] = useState("");
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const onSubmit = (form) => {
    const query = "MATCH (u:User) {username: $username, password:$password}) RETURN u";
    const params = { username: form.username, password: form.password };
    let result = { query, params };
    setResult = JSON.stringify(result);
  };

  const { loading, first } = useReadCypher(result.query, result.params);
```

But that also doesn't seem to work properly.
I don't know how to call the `useReadCypher` without re-rendering my component and after my form is submitted.
Does anyone know how to do this?
I hope my question is clarified enough to help me.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the below code, I have updated the method. Hope it work for you.

```
function Login() {
  const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm();
  const **handleSubmit** = () => {
    const query = "MATCH (u:User) {username: $username, password:$password}) RETURN u";
    const params = { username: form.username, password: form.password };
    const { loading, first } = useReadCypher(query, params);
  };

  return (
    <form
      className="loginForm bg-white shadow-md rounded-md px-8 pt-6 pb-8 mb-4 mx-8"
      onSubmit={**handleSubmit**}>
```

Comment: The ** results in unexpected token error.

Comment: const **handleSubmit** = ()  replace to const handleSubmit = () 

onSubmit={**handleSubmit**}> replace this to onSubmit={handleSubmit}>

Comment: I wanted to highlight that code but it show **.

Comment: Since I used **handleSubmit** in the const of useForm, I can't declare it again.

Comment: If I remove it from **const {register,handleSubmit}** I get the error it isn't in a react component

Comment: You can rename handleSubmit to onSubmit={onSubmit}